# C# Array numero proximo

Tags: c#, array

Estou precisando de ajuda não sei mas onde recorrer. O problema e o seguinte temos uma Array do tipo Double.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Temos uma variável x = 91.30 na Array (a) o valor mais próximo é 91.39.
Eu queria saber como fazer a variável y receber o valor do índice 91.39 que é o mais próximo de x. no caso 91.30

Comment: Seria interessantíssimo você colocar o código na publicação para que possamos fazer os devidos testes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar Linq para obter esse número, e até brevemente o índice no Array onde ele se encontra.

Não esqueça de importar a biblioteca `System.Linq` no começo do código.

```
double[] arr = new double[] { 1.5, 1.7, 1.88, 2.0, 2.6, 3.0 };

double numeroBase = 1.65;
double numeroDaArray = arr.Aggregate((x,y) => Math.Abs(x - numeroBase) < Math.Abs(y - numeroBase) ? x : y);
int indice = Array.IndexOf(arr, numeroDaArray);

Console.WriteLine("Número {0} no índice {1} é o mais próximo de {2}.", numeroDaArray, indice, numeroBase);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1R2nqt).</sup>